# Looking for a design-to-code software like Macaw

Tags: web-apps, html, web-development, html-editor

I've recently discovered people invented this awesome thing called [Macaw](http://macaw.co/). You draw the interface, and it transforms it into HTML & CSS. How awesome is that?

But there is little in terms of help for Macaw - guessing it's not very used. So, could you recommend me something else, and free of charge too, if possible?

Also, what would be the key words? 'design-to-code' doesn't return much on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here you are:

- https://webflow.com - the chief Macaw competitor, great UI. It has a free plan which allows only two pages. You can export sites created in the platform to static html; it also has CMS and allows for dynamic content).

You can also take a look at solutions such as:

- https://zeplin.io/
- https://avocode.com/
- https://sympli.io/

These are great tools which let you prepare a psd file for slicing. They are not free but have freemium plans. Unlike Webflow, they do not produce web pages but rather let you define sliced objects' dimension, colour codes, etc. That is, they enormously facilitate the designer to developer communication.

And then you have tools such as:

- https://www.google.com/webdesigner (free)
- http://www.artisteer.com (paid)
- http://www.xara.com/eu/web-designer/ (paid)

These look like classic illustration editors, but they are not; they serve the specific purpose of designing themes for web and as such they have all the functionalities for an artist to design an interactive interface.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Webflow. Also, I think macaw is on hiatus until next release with invision (no updates [since January 2016](http://download.macaw.co/))

Awesome resources as well: [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APiSNBkyD5Y&list=PLPmnoMVpkxfg4836eS6CrBpt8yha0ezaf&index=3) describes "How to build a One Page Business Website in Webflow".

Full Disclosure: some bias since I work for Webflow, but before joining the company I used the program daily as a web designer... Webflow changed my life. :)

Comment: Ahem... While you've included several links, could it be you've missed the most important one: where to find Webflow? ;) While on it, could you include why you'd recomment his? What makes it specifically useful in this context? Thanks in advance!